# Panel AutoScrollPosition leaves white spaces between elements

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

Can some one explain why the code below leaves white spaces between inserted elements and how to fix it?

[image]

```
private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (outLine.Data != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outLine.Data))
        {
            this.lineCount++;
            Label TestLBL = new Label();
            TestLBL.Text = outLine.Data.TrimStart();
            TestLBL.Name = this.lineCount.ToString();
            TestLBL.AutoSize = true;
            TestLBL.Location = new Point(10, panel1.Controls.Count * 20);

            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                panel1.Controls.Add(TestLBL);
                panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(10, this.lineCount * 20);


            }));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't using a FlowLayoutPanel, you would have to compensate for the scrollbar position in order to get the correct location:

```
TestLBL.Location = new Point(10, panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + panel1.Controls.Count * 20);
```

You should probably put all of that GUI control creation code inside that BeginInvoke block.  GUI controls like to be created on the GUI thread.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks a lot!!